# Use Crystal Reports 2011 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to use crystal reports 2011 in visual studio 2010. How can i use it?

Comment: Are you looking for a tutorial or do you have any troubles using it?

Comment: i have tried it but i couldn't find the reference that can i add into the project.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560630/vs-2010-net-4-cannot-found-crystalreports-references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of links. Try it out.

http://www.sourcehints.com/articles/how-to-use-crystal-report-2010-in-vs2010.html

http://forums.asp.net/t/1687320.aspx/1

This will help you with the referencing problem:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560630/vs-2010-net-4-cannot-found-crystalreports-references