# how to use crystal reports in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am developing c# application using visual studio 2010.. Now i want to use crystal report in my project but I am using Visual studio 2010 first time.. So when I add crystal report in project then it creates .mht file and ask me to download SAP crystal reports..

http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp

Several downloading options as shown in above link.. I have tried by downloading several setups which includes
1.SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio 2010 - Click Once
2.SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio 2010 - Click Once (32 Bit)

But after installation of this still no effect in visual studio and still asking me for download..

One more thing I want mention that my system is of 32 bit thats why i cant go for 64b bit..

Comment: i dont think so that there is much difference between VS 2008 and 2010 regarding functionality, if you have used Vs 2008 then making crystal report is same

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Crystal Reports 2011 in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324765/use-crystal-reports-2011-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found  the solutions..

By downloading the product 
1)SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio 2010 - Standard

As this works fine and integrated successfully with visual studio 2010 IDE..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same question as here:

[Use Crystal Reports 2011 in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324765/use-crystal-reports-2011-in-visual-studio-2010)